# I know I have more free space

Tags: linux, storage, hard-drive, opensuse

I'm trying to track down where all my hard disk space went. I have 1TB total space and, according to my system, 433GB used. However, I know I have more as I don't have any large files or folders that I'm aware of. The following shows the top 10 directories.

```
du -cks *|sort -rn|head
```

It says the /var folder is taking up 480GB but when I go into that folder, there is nothing sizeable (i run this from root or '/' w/ su permissions).

What am I missing? Are there any hidden files that that code doesn't pick up? For reference, I am using opensuse 11.3, if that makes a diff.

Comment: What does "there is nothing sizeable" mean? Keep checking all the subfolders in `/var`: `# du -s /var/* | sort -rn | cut -f2 | xargs -d '\n' du -sh` | head?

Comment: How does your total compare with your top `n`?

Comment: quanta, your answer helped me pin it down...turned out it was the /var/lib/mysql folder...now, I need to figure out what to do w/ that....if you put your solution as an answer below I will accept it. thx!

Answer (score 7):

If you do the recursive du as suggested, and calculate all space for the entire var tree, and it doesn't add up to the total used, you might want to check for an unlinked file handle that has been left open.  This can happen with improper logrotate scripts that delete or move a log that is still actively being written to.  You unlink the file (delete the inode, therefore ls doesn't report it anymore) but the process is still writing to it.

lsof is not typically a standard install, so you will have to install it through whatever means OpenSuse uses, then run:
`lsof +L -a /var`

You'll see output like

```
COMMAND   PID      USER     FD    TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK   NODE NAME
httpd     32287    apache   14w   REG  253,7  3020256     1    121  /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

There will be many files show up, but what you are looking for is one that has a large value in the size column, and a 0 in the NLINK column (and isn't marked deleted).  That file is still being written to, but is not linked any more.

You can then correct it by terminating the process that has the unlinked file handle open.

Answer (score 4):

All that means is that you haven't found the files where all the space is being used.  It should be trivial to find, because if `du` is finding it at the top level, then it's sitting on the filesystem.

If a `du -s /directory` shows space used, but a `du -s /directory/*` doesn't, then the problem is in hidden ("starts with a .") files or directories directly in `/directory`.  If there is a discrepancy between `df` and `du` (larger than can be explained by rounding differences) then you've got deleted but unreleased files consuming space.

Answer (score 1):

> quanta, your answer helped me pin it down...turned out it was the
>   /var/lib/mysql folder...now, I need to figure out what to do w/
>   that...

Have you used MySQL replication? **If so**, maybe the binary logs is filling up your hard disk. It can be remove automatically by setting the `expire_logs_days` from `mysql>` prompt:

```
mysql> set global expire_logs_days = 7;
```

*(also change the `my.cnf` to make it permanent)*

You should set it no lower than maximum number of days your slaves might lag behind the master.

**If not**, continue checking for all databases in `/var/lib/mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything mounted below **/var**?

There might be data hidden "under" a mountpoint.

### Example:

```
mkdir /var/test
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/test/data.dat bs=1M count=16
```

Now mount something at /var/test - you will not see where the missing 16MB are.